# Automate Tableau- Identify broken report

Tags: automation, tableau-api

I'm working on solving the below problem, not sure whether I'm on the right track. Kindly share your experience if you already solved similar problem.

We have over 1000+ tableau report created using datasource varing from Orace, MySQL, Excel and others. The challenge we are trying to address is, most of the data comes from dataware house. Based on requirement if developers change the database view or column name or completly drop the table (rare scenario) there is not an easy way to regression test the impacted reports.

I have tried the following things,

1. Using python to download all the tableau workbook(.tbw/.tbwx) from the server and modify the extension as '.xml'. Parse the xml tree for  and  identify the column mismatch. Depends on the complexity of the tableau report, the xml structure is not providing a reliable output every time.
2. Using selenium to launch the report in a browser and refresh the report. if there is no error message 'assume the report is not broken;

What is the best approach to regression test all the published report?. Is there any opensource tool available? I'm not very much interested in the data comparison atleast for now.

Comment: If you're on version 10, perhaps the Document API might be of use for this situation. http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/10/tableau-101-includes-api-improvements-client-library-59869?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have gone through the REST API documentation. I can use those endpoints to query, post or create a new record in the tableau. However, my interest is to identify broken report.

Comment: After spending two weeks, I was able to identify the necessary tableau end-points using fiddler and I developed a python script using request and beautiful soup ( To parse the HTML SAML authentication response ) package which is working like a charm in identifying the broken tableau report.